# MongoDB - show dbs and show log without clusterAdmin role

Tags: mongodb, privileges, replicaset

Is there a way to give a user on a MongoDB replica set the ability to use 'show dbs' and 'show log' without giving them the clusterAdmin role?

Various user interfaces (e.g., robomongo) show a list of databases when you connect.  Without the ability to 'show dbs', no databases are listed.

Thank you!

Comment: you can give them different permissions as described in this comment https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11234?focusedCommentId=442260&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-442260

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the post you referenced, they are adding the clusterAdmin role to the user in the 'admin' database (via a userSource entry or via a full user).  I'd like to avoid granting the full clusterAdmin role and just give the ability to 'show dbs' and 'show log'.

Comment: the suggestion is to use http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/privilege-documents/#admin.system.users.otherDBRoles instead of clusterAdmin

Comment: actually, this is about listDatabases.  I don't think you want to give show log xxx to anyone other than admin - the logs contain a lot of detailed info about pretty much everything in the cluster.

Comment: I have the command to set 'otherDBRoles' for a user (below).  I'm confused as to what to set, though.  Do I give the 'read' role on the database where listDatabases is stored?  e.g., for local - `db.system.users.update({"user":"myUser"},{$set:{'otherDBRoles':{'local':['read']}}},false,false)`

Comment: I'll leave this note here for others.  From what I've read, 2.4 does not offer a way to give individual action access to users, only the predefined roles.  2.6 adds the ability to createRole and define your own list of resources/actions for the role.  As of this writing, [http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6/](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6/) discusses the new feature. _New in version 2.5.3: MongoDB gives administrators access to roles through the role-management commands. Administrators can use the commands to create custom roles._

Answer (score 3):

<sub>The question was apparently written with an older version in mind, but since at least 3.2.9 this has been possible.</sub>

The command `show dbs` is a wrapper around the command `listDatabases`, which is grantable. So first create a role that does only the latter.

```
db.runCommand({createRole:"justListDatabases",privileges:[{resource:{cluster:true},
               actions:["listDatabases"]}],roles:[]})
```

Then grant it to the user.

```
db.grantRolesToUser("app_RO_user",["justListDatabases"])
```

**NOTE that `show dbs` interrogates each database for its size, [which uses locks](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listDatabases/).** So depending on how your MongoDB instances tolerate such locks you might want to grant this cluster privilege to low privilege users judiciously.